# Why does the href="http://...." direct me to "https://..."?

Tags: html, http, hyperlink, https, href

Alright, this is the case:

I have a website. When not logged in, it is a `http` connection.

On my homepage I have a link to another site:

```
<a href="http://www.somesite.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">www.somesite.com</a>
```

So far so good, when pressing the link it goes to the site.

But when I log in to my website, I have a secured connection (`https`).

Now, when I press the same link, it opens `https://www.somesite.com` although I have the link hardcoded as `http` in my code. And the `somesite.com` does not provide a `https` connection, so the browser is complaining.

How is this possible and how do I get the browser to just follow the hardcoded url?

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't? `http://www.somesite.com/` surely returns a response that redirects to `https://www.somesite.com/`.

Comment: When you say 'log into your website," what exactly do you mean? Are you talking about logging in as a developer to make changes, or as a user accessing it?

Comment: @ikegami No it does not, because when I have no secure connection, I just get redirected to `http://www.somesite.com/`

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you checked if your browser auto forwards to https when it's already on an https website?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I have no secure connection"?  Do you mean "when you aren't logged in"? If so, that doesn't mean there's no redirection happening; it just means it's happening conditionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many websites support a non-secured (http) connection up to the point of user authentication. At that point, many sites will redirect to a secured (https) authentication mechanism and conduct all subsequent communication with the authenticated user over https.

The site you are accessing is being redirected by the server to the secure connection. That is why when you access the site via your link via http, the server redirects you to the secure site. If you are familiar with the dev tools in your browser, you can probably follow a network trace of the exchange between you and your site and see the redirect at some point in the communication exchange.